# How to return to a specific point in a MIPS program

Tags: mips

I am writing a function in MIPS that will divide two fractions stored in the a0-a3 registers, like so: (a0/a1) and (a2/a3). I already have a function that will multiply both fractions together, so all I need to do is switch the numerator and denominator on the second fraction and call my multiplication function. I have that part figured out, however I also need to make sure that the numerator retains the sign, meaning that if I flip the second fraction around, and it's a negative, then I need to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by -1. I have written a separate function to do this for me, but after calling that function I don't know how to jump back to where I was. Here is the code:

```
f_div:

#Flip the second fraction (a2/a3) -> (a3/a2)
add   $t0, $a2, $0
add   $a2, $a3, $0
add   $a3, $t0, $0

ble   $a3, $0, f_flipsign #Branch if $a3 <= 0

#I need to be able to jump back here from f_flipsign
#How do I arbitrarily jump back to a location in the program without
#direct access to the PC?

add   $s0, $ra, $0 #Save $ra so I don't lose it when I jal f_mul 
jal   f_mul
add   $ra, $s0, $0 #Put the original $ra back 
# Also, is there a better way to do this ^

jr    $ra #Jump back to main

f_flipsign:

li    $t0, -1
mult  $a2, $t0
mflo  $a2
mult  $a3, $t0
mflo  $a2

jr  ? #How do I make this jump back to the middle of f_div?
```

I have researched and studied for hours today and I can't seem to figure this out. I understand how these instructions are formatted, I just need to know how to accomplish this one thing. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Probably `j <label>` where `<label>` is the label of the instruction you want to jump to.

Comment: So can I just create a new label and throw it into the middle of my f_div function?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  I'm not familiar with MIPS or the assembler you are using.  I just read one of the instruction set summaries on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *f_flipsign* subroutine is in fact some code you just need to execute only in that case, then maybe it does not have to be a subroutine at all and just change the branch condition and add the flip sign code there.

In that case, just change the `ble` to a `bgt` to skip the flip code, e.g.:

```
  bgt   $a3, $0, dont_flip #Branch if $a3 > 0
# Your code to flip sign
  li    $t0, -1
  mult  $a2, $t0
  mflo  $a2
  mult  $a3, $t0
  mflo  $a2
dont_flip:
# Code continues here (whether it flipped sign or not)
```

If *flip_sign* is a subroutine that may be called from many places, then you should use *jal-code-jr*, but you have to preserve `$ra` somewhere (usually the stack) so that it is not lost when calling the subroutine.
Assuming you have preserved `$ra`, then you would write something like this:

```
  bgt   $a3, $0, continue #Branch if $a3 > 0
  jal f_flipsign
continue:
# Code continues here (whether it flipped sign or not)
```

and in your f_flipsign subroutine end with:

```
  jr $ra
```

Comment: Awesome, very helpful! This answered a lot of my questions. Everywhere I go to find code examples it just explains the format of each 32-bit instruction and the number (and type) of its arguments, so it's hard to find some simple code implementations like this. Thank you for your time!